# How to efficiently query database, adding row if necessary, and get results

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL Server Compact in my C# project.  My database has a Users table that has two columns - an ID column (PRIMARY KEY) and a Username column.  I keep track of various users that interface with my system by inserting their username in the Users table.

When a user contacts the system, I want to record their name in the table if they aren't already there.  Obviously, I could add the UNIQUE keyword to the Username column, but that means I need to handle exceptions for duplicate entry attempts.  Once the name is in the table - either because it already exists or I had to add it - I need to get the corresponding ID.

Here's some working code to shoot at.

```
public void GetUserId(string username)
{
    using (SqlCeCommand selcmd= new SqlCeCommand(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @user", conn))
    {
        selcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
        SqlCeResultSet rs = selcmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
        if (!rs.HasRows)
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand inscmd= new SqlCeCommand(
                "INSERT INTO users (username) values (@user)", conn))
            {
                inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
                inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            rs = selcmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
        }

        rs.ReadFirst();

        return (rs.GetInt32(rs.GetOrdinal("id")));
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Well, this should definitely go in a stored procedure. Then, no matter what you do, it will only be one trip to the database.

Comment: Agreed.  The only problem is that SQL Server Compact does not support stored procedures.

Comment: Yep.. used on th internets for lots of goods opens sources peoples.

Comment: Your solution is the best approach for SQL Server Compact

Comment: Thanks, @ErikEJ.  If you'll post a quick answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is the best approach for SQL Server Compact - the other proposed solutions use syntax not available in SQL Server Compact

Answer (score -1):

you could do this:

```
INSERT IF NOT EXISTS INTO `tablename` yadda yadda yadda
```

that won't raise an exception.

This is an SQL question, not a c# or .net one, by the way

Comment: SQL Server Compact doesn't appear to support the 'INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ...' syntax.

Comment: then see the comments on your question =P

Comment: But another thing you can do is SELECT looking for the name, and if no rows are returned, then INSERT

Comment: I understand, but using another database solution is not an option.  The point is, I have a working solution, but I'm not convinced it's the most efficient solution.  That's what I'm looking for.  I'll post the working code in a moment for potshots.